# Yocto: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.16.3.bb:do_configure in yocto

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, bitbake, gstreamer-1.0

I am always facing a problem if i wanted to build yocto or the qt toolchain.

for example in the first run i have give the following command where the issue occurs the first time:

```
bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5
```

following error message occurs:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.6"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 = "dunfell:9ee329c18fbe0c42eaf3d43657ea30591f79143b"
meta-oe              = "dunfell:346681e7bf9c78008a845fc89031be4fd4ceb3a1"
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "dunfell:9ee329c18fbe0c42eaf3d43657ea30591f79143b"
meta-qt5             = "dunfell:0d8eb956015acdea7e77cd6672d08dce18061510"
meta-raspberrypi     = "dunfell:77190af02d48adc2b28216775e6318e9eeda571c"
meta-multimedia      
meta-python          
meta-networking      = "dunfell:346681e7bf9c78008a845fc89031be4fd4ceb3a1"

Initialising tasks: 100% |##################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:02
Sstate summary: Wanted 0 Found 0 Missed 0 Current 329 (0% match, 100% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-1.16.3-r0 do_configure: meson failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run-time dependency gstreamer-sdp-1.0 found: YES 1.16.3
| Run-time dependency gstreamer-tag-1.0 found: YES 1.16.3
| Run-time dependency gstreamer-video-1.0 found: YES 1.16.3
| Run-time dependency gstreamer-check-1.0 found: YES 1.16.3
| Found CMake: NO
| Run-time dependency gstreamer-gl-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
| Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency gstreamer-gl-1.0
| 
| meson.build:283:0: ERROR: Subproject directory not found and gst-plugins-base.wrap file not found
|
```

How can i solve this problem any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you prepare your PC for the yocto build by installing host packages? https://docs.yoctoproject.org/brief-yoctoprojectqs/index.html

Comment: Hi @FlorianBerndl, yes i did. I was so frustrated that i have setup a "clean" yocto which have solves that issue... I will close this and thanks so much for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue as well and was able to track down the cause (though it probably doesn't apply to the original query if it was resolved by a clean build). In my case, I was building for an ELGFS Qt based system. There's a check in the meson.build file in gstreamer1.0-plugins-base that will disable the gstgl library build if an OpenGL Window system isn't found, and this was being triggered for me. gstreamer 1.16 does not support EGL as the window system but 1.18 does. Yocto upgraded to gstreamer 1.18 with the hardknott release, but we were relying on multiple supporting 3rd party recipes that were still on dunfell and couldn't upgrade.

In our case, gstreamer had been included as a dependency from qtmultimedia, but this was determined to be extraneous and could be resolved by excluding qtmultimedia or using a .bbappend file to remove gstreamer from the PACKAGECONFIG. If gstreamer is actually needed then the options are:

1. Use a windowing system (e.g., weston, or a custom wayland compositor), or
2. See if the gstreamer 1.18 recipe from hardknott can be made to work in the existing project, or
3. See if the entire project can be upgraded to use the hardknott release, so that gstreamer 1.18 is used by default.

Comment: Hi @Travis R,  great hint. :D and thank you for the analyze.

Comment: thanks for the analyze, got the same error when building Yocto Dunfell release with gstreamer 1.16, and removing gstreamer from qtmultimedia's PACKAGECONFIG fix the error.