# gst-plugins-base.wrap file not found

Tags: gstreamer, raspberry-pi3, yocto

I am getting the same error as per the link
[Yoto: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.16.3.bb:do_configure in yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492990/yoto-gstreamer1-0-plugins-bad-1-16-3-bbdo-configure-in-yocto).

The difference is I am using Yocto dunfell branch commit: 40e448301edf142dc00a0ae6190017adac1e57b2 which is 3.1.3

Was the issue is with Poky recipes or open-embedded recipes?

I couldn't find solution anywhere.

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.3"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta
meta-poky            = "HEAD:40e448301edf142dc00a0ae6190017adac1e57b2"
meta-oe
meta-python
meta-multimedia
meta-networking      = "HEAD:2a5c534d2b9f01e9c0f39701fccd7fc874945b1c"
meta-raspberrypi     = "HEAD:f0c75016f06c0395d1e76fde0ef1beb71eaf404a"
meta-qt5             = "HEAD:1650757f4182435a63985f73e477ed80927f0eac"

| Found CMake: NO
| Run-time dependency gstreamer-gl-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
| Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency gstreamer-gl-1.0
|
| meson.build:283:0: ERROR: Subproject directory not found and gst-plugins-base.wrap file not found
```

I didn't got into any issue when I was using 'zeus' branch.
I appreciate everyone help.

Comment: I posted an answer on the [question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68094114/1664052), which may or may not apply to you. Suggest looking at the meson log file for the gstreamer1.0-plugins-base build and seeing if it reports a missing platform or window system, which would prevent the glgst library from being included.